# Comparing 2 parameters values

Tags: xml, xslt

I can't seem to figure out this basic demand.

Trying to match the parameters token & id to print the value of the given language.

Tried for each statements first but these just keep printing all data since they don't break out. With templates it's getting closer but I'm missing something.

the xml:

```
<dictionary>
<tokens>
    <afk token="G133" symbol="AIP"/>
    <afk token="G001" symbol="APP"/>
    <afk token="G002" symbol="AUDIT"/>
    <afk token="G209" symbol="BACC"/>
    <afk token="G003" symbol="BASE"/>
</tokens>
<translations>
    <item id="G001">
        <en>Actual Payout Percentage</en>
        <de>Effektiver Auszahlungs-Prozentsatz</de>
        <es>Porcentaje de pago real</es>
        <zh></zh>
        <zs></zs>
        <fr>Pourcentage de paiement réel</fr>
        <it></it>
        <nl></nl>
    </item>
    <item id="G002">
        <en>Audit</en>
        <de>Audit</de>
        <es>Auditoría</es>
        <zh></zh>
        <zs></zs>
        <fr>Audit</fr>
        <it></it>
        <nl></nl>
    </item>
    <item id="G003">
        <en>Base value, start value, restart value</en>
        <de>Basiswert, Startwert, Neustart-Wert</de>
        <es>Valor de base, valor de inicio, valor de reinicio</es>
        <zh></zh>
        <zs></zs>
        <fr>Valeur de base, valeur de démarrage, valeur de redémarrage</fr>
        <it></it>
        <nl></nl>
    </item>
    <item id="G004">
        <en>Bill Box Level</en>
        <de>Bill-Box-Füllstand</de>
        <es>Nivel de la caja de billetes</es>
        <zh></zh>
        <zs></zs>
        <fr>Niveau de caisse à billets</fr>
        <it></it>
        <nl></nl>
    </item>
    <item id="G005">
        <en>Bill Count</en>
        <de>Banknoten-Zählung</de>
        <es>Recuento de billetes</es>
        <zh></zh>
        <zs></zs>
        <fr>Comptage de billets</fr>
        <it></it>
        <nl></nl>
    </item>
    <item id="G006">
        <en>Bill Drop</en>
        <de>Banknoten-Drop</de>
        <es>Drop de billetes</es>
        <zh></zh>
        <zs></zs>
        <fr>Recettes en billets</fr>
        <it></it>
        <nl></nl>
    </item>
    <item id="G007">
        <en>Bill(s)</en>
        <de>Banknote(n) </de>
        <es>Billete(s)</es>
        <zh></zh>
        <zs></zs>
        <fr>Billet(s)</fr>
        <it></it>
        <nl></nl>
    </item>
</translations>
```

xsl:

```
<body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//afk"/> 
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>    
<xsl:template match="afk">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@token = ../../translations/item/@id">
            <strong> 
                <xsl:value-of select="@symbol"/> <br/>
            </strong>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../translations/item/en"/> <br/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <strong> 
                <xsl:value-of select="@symbol"/> <br/>
            </strong>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I have no idea how the parser gets to this result:

AIP

APP

Actual Payout Percentage

AUDIT

Actual Payout Percentage

BACC

BASE

Actual Payout Percentage

Comment: What is the result (as code) you are trying to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a key

```
  <xsl:key name="ref" match="item" use="@id"/>
```

and use it e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="afk">
      <strong>
          <xsl:value-of select="@symbol"/>
      </strong>
      <xsl:value-of select="key('ref', @token)/en"/>
      <br/>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuNR

Comment: Beautiful, didn't know about this technique. Thank you!